# Azure Key Vault Access Policy Doesn't Work For Groups

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-active-directory

Access policies via groups on Azure Key Vault don't seem to work.

If I create a new key vault

```
 New-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $vaultName
```

And check the keys (which there aren't any of currently)

```
 Get-AzureKeyVaultKey -VaultName $vaultName
```

That works.

If I add access to a group that the current user is a member of

```
$group = (Get-AzureRmADGroup -SearchString 'All Developers')[0].Id
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $vaultName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ObjectId $group -PermissionsToKeys all -PermissionsToSecrets all
```

And remove direct access

```
Remove-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $vaultName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -UserPrincipalName $upn
```

The list operation now fails

```
Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $vaultName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

Get-AzureKeyVaultKey : Operation "list" is not allowed
```

How can I permission by group?

Comment: This related documentation may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-group-permissions-for-apps
Though also see this issue I raised with it: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/9729

Answer (score 5):

I discovered today that it works for users in permissioned group objects. Doesn't work for service principals in those groups.

In other words, if I authenticate using a client id and client secret, the associated service principal must have an access policy directly set on the key vault. If I permission a security group, a user in that group can in fact access the key vault. I guess this has something to do with how the JWT includes security groups in it with users, but not service principals...

Answer (score 4):

The reason that adding an access policy to a group is that it isn't supported. If you look at the help for `Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy` there is this for ObjectId

```
-ObjectId <Guid>
    Specifies the object ID of the user or service principal in Azure Active Directory for which to grant permissions.

    Required?                    true
    Position?                    named
    Default value                none
    Accept pipeline input?       true(ByPropertyName)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

As you can see ObjectId only supports either Service principals or users.

This is reflected in the parameters of the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/master/src/ResourceManager/KeyVault/Commands.KeyVault/Commands/SetAzureKeyVaultAccessPolicy.cs) for `Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy` and further up the chain the [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt620025.aspx) when posting to

```
    https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/{vault-name}?api-version={api-version}
```

The payload contains the `objectId` parameter which is defined as

> Specifies the object ID of a user or service principal in the Azure Active Directory tenant for the vault. The ID must be specified as a GUID.

I would imagine that this functionality will be added at some point in future, but at the moment it isn't possible.

Comment: But there are a maximum of 10 access policies that can be put on a single key vault. So the limitation is basically that key vaults are unusable for more than 10 unique users? I just want to make sure I understand before concluding that Azure key vault is completely useless for my purposes

Comment: @Jeff My personal solution to that has been to have a single Key Vault per application. On both SKUs they are cheap enough to be irrelevant. I usually deploy a vault with the rest of a resource group and lock down its permissions solely to that one app.

Comment: That would be nice...but for testing purposes, I need real users to have access to the key vault...and I'm not comfortable passing around client secrets.

Comment: @Jeff Could you write a new question about it? what you're looking to achieve and I'll have a think see if anything springs to mind

Comment: Your answer is actually incorrect. I discovered today that it works for users in permissioned group objects. Doesn't work for service principals in those groups.

Comment: Groups can now be assigned to Key Vaults, though the documentation hasn't yet been updated. :)

Comment: 0

down vote
 

One updated piece of documentation that now shows granting permissions to a security group is example 6 here: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603625.aspx)

Comment: executed according to the documentation mentioned by @sandshadow but still didn't work for us.

Answer (score 0):

This `Access Denied` / `403 Forbidden` error can also happen when an app has made requests to a Key Vault **before** it was added to the Azure Active Directory Group.

Perhaps this has something to do with caching of service principal information on the App Service instance? I was unable to find documentation of this.

**Solution: restart the App Service.**